# Optimising a PHP If/Else statement

Tags: php, optimization, case, if-statement

I'm attempting to optimise the following PHP If/Else statement. Could I rewrite the code to make use to `case` and `switch`, or should I leave it as it is, or what?

Code:

```
if(empty($_GET['id'])){
    include('pages/home.php');
}elseif ($_GET['id'] === '13') {
    include('pages/servicestatus.php');
}elseif(!empty($_GET['id'])){
    $rawdata = fetch_article($db->real_escape_string($_GET['id']));
    if(!$rawdata){
        $title = "";
        $meta['keywords'] = "";
        $meta['description'] = "";
    }else{
        $title = stripslashes($rawdata['title']);
        $meta['keywords'] = stripslashes($rawdata['htmlkeywords']);
        $meta['description'] = stripslashes($rawdata['htmldesc']);
        $subs = stripslashes($rawdata['subs']);
        $pagecontent = "<article>" . stripslashes($rawdata['content']) . "</article>";
    }
    include("includes/header.php");
    echo $pagecontent;
    if(!$rawdata){
        error_404();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate switch statements, but its personal preference to be honest. As far as further optimization i'd suggest taking a look at some form of assembly language. It will give you some general ideas on how to make conditional statements more efficient. That is, it will give you a different out look on things.

```
if(!empty($_GET['id'])) 
    {

    if($_GET['id'] == '13')
    {
        include('pages/servicestatus.php');
    }
    else
    {
        $rawdata = fetch_article($db->real_escape_string($_GET['id']));

        if (!$rawdata) {

            $title = "";
            $meta['keywords'] = "";
            $meta['description'] = "";
        } else {

            $title = stripslashes($rawdata['title']);
            $meta['keywords'] = stripslashes($rawdata['htmlkeywords']);
            $meta['description'] = stripslashes($rawdata['htmldesc']);
            $subs = stripslashes($rawdata['subs']);
            $pagecontent = "<article>" . stripslashes($rawdata['content']) . "</article>";
        }

        include("includes/header.php");
        echo $pagecontent;
        if (!$rawdata) {

            error_404();
        }
    }
} 
else 
{
    include('pages/home.php');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look into breaking up your code into a MVC form; that would make it much easier to maintain your code.  At least put the last clause into another file, probably called `default.php` and `include` it.  Also, you might create an array of id => file key/value sets, lookup the id, and include the file.

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $pages = array(
        0 => 'home.php',
        13 => 'servicestatus.php'
    );
    if (isset($pages[$_GET['id']])) {
        include('pages/' . $pages[$_GET['id']]);
    } else {
        include('pages/default.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: As much as I would like to, the code is part of a content management system, and the majority of content is dynamic. :(

Answer (score 2):

Well i don't think it's necessary to switch to a swith
but you could change

```
} elseif (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
```

to just

```
}else{
```

Answer (score 2):

`switch` would be appropriate if you had several discrete values for `$_GET['id']` that you were checking for.

One suggestion I can make for the sake of readability is that

```
} elseif (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
```

only needs to be

```
} else {
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, switch is evaluate once, is efficient than `if elseif`,
and is easier to maintain with this given structure

```
switch ($_GET['id'])
{
  case 13: ... break;
  case 0 : ... break;
  default: ... break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know, if you should, or should not, but here I wouldnt. The main reason is, that there is at least one statement, you can omit, and then, you will have just a `if-elseif-else`-Statement

```
if (empty($_GET['id'])) { /* code */ }
elseif ($_GET['id'] === '13') { /* code */ }
elseif (!empty($_GET['id'])) { /* code* }
```

is the same as

```
if (empty($_GET['id'])) { /* code */ }
elseif ($_GET['id'] === '13') { /* code */ }
else { /* code* }
```

In the block after that, the statement `if(!$rawdata)` is also duplicated.

Comment: Should or should not? You should always attempt to optimize your code. You sir are one of the main reasons for "bloatware".

Comment: 1) "premature optimization is the root of all evil", 2) micro-optimization 3) readable code is better than hackish code ;) and last but not least 4) nothing to optimize here ;) I dont say, you should _never_ optimize, but here it really doesnt matter.